# error when building openCV for android in windows

Tags: java, android, opencv, cmake

I have a problem when building openCV for android. I follow this steps:
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Android2.3.0
for build openCV in windows from command line.

when enter this commands:

cd opencv\android\

scripts\cmake_android.cmd

in 94% show this errors:

> [ 94%] Generating bin/opencv_test_java.apk
>
> ```
>  [echo] Gathering info for opencv_test_java...
> ```
>
> Target '-setup' failed with message '../../../ resolve to a path with
>   no project .properties file for project
>   C:\opencv\android\build\modules\java\android_test'.
>
> Cannot execute '-build-setup' - '-setup' failed or was not executed.
>        [echo] hasCode = false. Skipping aidl/renderscript/R.java Cannot execute '-compile' - '-build-setup' failed or was not executed. Cannot
>   execute '-dex' - '-compile' failed or was not executed. Target
>   '-package-resources' failed with message 'The following error occurred
>   wh ile executing this line:
>   D:\necessitas\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:808: null returned: 1'.
>   Cannot execute '-package' - '-dex' failed or was not executed. Cannot
>   execute '-do-debug' - '-package' failed or was not executed. Cannot
>   execute 'debug' - '-do-debug' failed or was not executed.
>
> BUILD FAILED D:\necessitas\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:440:
>   ../../../ resolve to a path w ith no project.properties file for
>   project C:\opencv\android\build\modules\java\ android_test
>
> Total time: 1 second make[2]: ***
>   [modules/java/android_test/bin/opencv_test_java-debug.apk] Error 1
>   make[1]: ***
>   [modules/java/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_java_android_project.dir/all]
>   Error 2 make: *** [all] Error 2
>
> make failed
>
> c:\opencv\android\scripts>

I'm update my android-sdk but also show this error. please help me!

thanks

sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

for this problem I download new android-sdk and don't update that. only set my path in windows:

```
ANDROID_SDK= "my sdk path"
```

and then run command `"cmake_android.cmd"`